# Add map values in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, map

I want to add javascript map values to existing lightning map type variable

Map type in Component

```
<aura:attribute name="CheckedRecsMap" type="Map"  default="{}"/>
```

In js declaring a new map and adding the values and I want to add the map values to the existing component maps (`CheckedRecsMap`).

```
 var CheckedRecsMap = component.get("v.CheckedRecsMap");
 var newMap= new Map();
 newMap.set(index,RowItemList[index]);

 component.set("v.CheckedRecsMap", newMap); //Will replace the old values
```

Basically, I want to push into Old map.

`CheckedRecsMap.set` and `CheckedRecsMap.push`  throws the error.

Comment: have you looked at the new lightning map component? I did it on trailhead and it seems pretty good. lightning:map is the component. can be found https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/example    Not sure if it will help but thought i would share

Comment: No, you misunderstood my question. I don't want lightning: map. I want to store key-value pair like apex Map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this "manually":

```
newMap.forEach((value,key)=>CheckedRecsMap.set(value,key));
```

Or, you could use an Object instead, which works out more like this:

```
var CheckedRecsObj = component.get("v.CheckedRecsObj");
var newMap = { arg1: 'value1', arg2: 'value2' };
Object.assign(CheckedRecsObj, newMap);
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox used object type and passed two arguments